# How to use LinkedList<T>.Find() method where T is an user-defined datatype (Objects)

Tags: c#, linked-list

The Find() method for LinkedList in C# works fine for strings, etc, but how to use it with structs, objects, etc?

Here is my code:

```
    {
        LinkedList<Item> TestLinkedList = new LinkedList<Item>();

        TestLinkedList.AddFirst(new Item(3, "Head n Shoulders"));

        TestLinkedList.AddAfter(TestLinkedList.First, new Item(45, "Dell"));

        //Get the 2nd node in the linklist

        Item c = new Item(3, "Head n Shoulders");

        LinkedListNode<Item> Node2 = TestLinkedList.Find(c);



        TestLinkedList.AddAfter((Node2), new Item(32, "Adidas"));

        foreach (Item i in TestLinkedList)
        {
            i.Print();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Its returning NULL for the Node2. Am I making the mistake at not using the unique Hashcode etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the `Find` to return the correct object, your `Item` class needs to override the `Equals` method. Of course you also need to override `GetHashCode` as well: although `Find` of `LinkedList` does not call `GetHashCode`, the two methods need to be changed together:

> Types that override `Equals(Object)` must also override `GetHashCode`; otherwise, hash tables might not work correctly.